# Read iPhone accelerometer gyroscope data in C#

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, ipad

Is there a C# library somewhere to read the gyroscope and/or accelerometer from an iPhone or iPad connected to a Windows7 PC via bluetooth?  I mean, is this sort of thing even possible?

I've looked at things like MobileDevice.dll, Manzana, and SharePodLib, but at the least those seem to get file data only.  Can the orientation data be read somehow (other than with ObjectiveC, Unity, etc.)?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: I'm sorry, where is the best place to ask such a question?

Answer (score 0):

although you should not ask those questions here i do happen to know a great library for cross platform development. Though i do not think it is possible to read accelerometer data from an iPhone trough Bluetooth unless you would write an app that should send this information trough Bluetooth.

The library is called [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) and you can actually create an app for android windows phone and ios in C# .net you might want to check it out ;)

Comment: Thanks Vincent; it's good to see some of you are actually helpful and constructive.  I was hoping there was a way to get at that information.  I can find stuff for application programming on iPhone, but this isn't an iPhone application...it's a x64 PC application.  I just want to be able to talk to the iPhone.

Comment: i still think to talk to an iPhone you would need something that listens and just as life you need to make sure people listen (aka write something that listens) but than again i'm no iPhone expert ;)